# QT: fail to find the file using a relative path

Tags: qt, filepath

(1) 
Say I have a file 
callingfile.cpp

It needs to read another file  newyearfile.frag in its child directory  "shaders".

This means it is like:

```
project:
  /prog1
  /prog1/callingfile.cpp
  /prog1/shaders/newyearfile.frag    (this file is added in Project.qrc)
```

Now in callingfile.cpp, I want to access newyearfile.frag

I tried:

```
shaders/newyearfile.frag
```

It doesn't work.

Then I tried:

```
./shaders/newyearfile.frag
```

It doesn't work

If I use

```
:/prog1/shaders/newyearfile.frag
```

Then it works.

But how come the relative paths cannot work?

(2)
But there is another case in the project file, it can use upper level of relative path.

```
project:
  /prog2
  /prog2/callme.h   (this file is in the Project.pro)
  /prog2/source/iwillcall.cpp
```

In iwillcall.cpp
it uses:

```
../callme.h
```

and it works.

(3) My guess:
Do you think the case (1), the file in .qrc override relative path?

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths are relative to the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (which is not necessarily the directory of your executable). You can also load it from the [Qt resources](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) if you prefer, but I see you probably already did.

With [QDir::currentPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#currentPath) you can get the path of the working directory.

Comment: please see my update. One example shows that it can use relative to the calling file. In that situation, parent ".." is used.

Comment: I don't see your point, sorry. You asked why relative paths are not working, but you seem to be using paths relative to the source file, which is commonly wrong. My answer reports the usual definition of "relative path", and you don't provide the exact code you're actually using. Referring to the Qt resources requires a ":" before the path.

Comment: My point is: in QT relative paths can be used related to the source file. I have listed the example in (2). But for files in QT resources, we cannot use the same way. They have different rules. They can only use the paths in the QT resource file.

Comment: You asked "how come the relative path cannot work?". Answer is it perfectly works according to the definition of relative path, which you seemed to ignore. Qt resources are something completely different and does not relate to my answer. If you can use relative paths now, I suppose the answer should be accepted.

Comment: However I can't reproduce the weird behaviour you reported. The path must be relative to the working dir, not to the source file. What class are you referring to?